# If $\lim_{|z|\to 1^-}u(z)=0$ then $u\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $u(z)$ be a complex valued harmonic function in $|z|<1$ and $\lim_{|z|\to 1^-}u(z)=0$. Then show that $u(z)$ is identically zero in $|z|<1$.

I am unable to understand that from where I start . I think Identity theorem helps , but how ?

Comment: Maximum principle?

Comment: How it helps ?>

Comment: If $0$ is a maximum of $|u(z)|$, then...?

Comment: How you can say that $0$ is the maximum value of $|u(z)|$ ?

Comment: Hmmm. Let $C_r = \{|z| < r\}$; for $C_r$ you have $|u(z)| < \max_{|z|=r} |u(z)|$. Let $r\to 1$. Then $|u(z)|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that $u$ is a complex-valued harmonic function for $|z|<1$ with $u\to 0$ as $|z|\to 1^{-}$.

The [Maximum Modulus Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) guarantees that the maximum (and minimum) for $u$ must occur on the boundary  $|z|=1$.  Inasmuch as $\lim_{|z|\to 1^{-}}u(z)=0$, then $u=0$ for all $|z|<1$.

We can also view this in the context of real analysis. Since $u$ is harmonic, both its real and imaginary parts satisfy Laplace's equation in the interior of the unit circle and vanish on the boundary.   The uniqueness theorem for the [Dirichlet Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem) applied to [Laplace's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) immediately leads to the expected answer.